# Try to remove circular dependency in c# diffrenet project

Tags: c#

I have 5 projects in a solution. A and B are two projects. B is already referencing A. Now I want to call methods in A from B. But the problem is circular dependency. I saw it being solved by using Events. I tried this:

A------->B(reference A)
B------->A(dependency)

Comment: move the method in A to B

Comment: sorry move method B to A, Ps it would be a lot better to conceptualize if you state why there are two projects and what type of projects! this would help give meaning to what and why you are doing what you doing. as from this... it should be clear why you have a dependency problem...

Answer (score 1):

You need a C project to solve this circular dependency.

the C project, includes all common classes and referencing by A and B project that you are already created.